# Delayed Wifi turn on after suspend in Ubuntu 20.04 Macbook Air 2017

Tags: wireless, 20.04, macbook-air

Active 5 days ago
Viewed 13 times
0

I have a Macbook Air 2017, and I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.04. Everything works great, but I have one annoying issue: when I close my laptop and it goes to suspend, and then when I open and log in it, I have no Wifi. I need to wait about 40-60 sec to have Wifi. Till that it behaves like not seeing any available Wifi network. Before Ubuntu 20.04 I used 18.04, and I had not issue like this.

What do you think?

Thank you in advance, Best wishes, Peter Mezei.

Comment: WiFi can't stay connected when the device is suspended.  Suspend saves the current state into memory and the device turns off.  After waking from suspend, a WiFi device needs to reestablish connection to the router.  Could this be what is happening for those 40-60 sec?

Comment: @Nmath No, when my laptop wakes from suspend, the wifi discovery does not find any available hotspot till that 40-60 sec. It is like some kind of driver issue. It did work great with Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: When I see my sys logs, I found this one: bgscan simple: Failed to enable signal strength monitoring

Comment: Hey, @PeterMezei I have one query which is not related to your problem. I am planning to install the latest Ubuntu on my MacBook air 2017 single boot and completely remove MacOS.

Will that be any big issue I may face? How about battery performance? I there around 50% reduction in batter performance? 

My main work in ubuntu will be, Python Development, Data Analysis, Flutter Development

Thanks a ton in advance

Comment: Hi @DhruvilPatel, I use my macbook 2017 with just Ubuntu 20.04. Almost everything works great. Webcam does not work out of the box - I dont mind it -, and I had a small issue about one of the usb port: somehow one usb port waked my laptop from suspend randomly. So I disabled the USB wakeup, and this solved my battery issue. Now there is no hidden battery drop. Battery life is like 7-9 hours, so pretty nice. If i close the lid and open it a day after, battery remains the same - cool. I use it as my main daily driver, I love it. For now the only issue is the slow wifi lookup after suspend.

Comment: @PeterMezei Thanks for the prompt answer. This is great. I will try ubuntu today or tomorrow once I backed up everything. I hope you find a solution. I will post if I will face same issue. Thanks again.